# Ubuntu 10.4 64 bit OS - 8GB RAM is shown as 7.8GB - why?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, memory, ubuntu-10.04

[image]

Ubuntu 10.4 64 bit OS - 8GB RAM is shown as 7.8GB - why? where is the rest gone? or is it just my math?

Comment: I cannot believe it took 2 years for somebody to point out the fact there is a difference between GB and GiB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the .2gb is being eaten by intergrated graphic or similar.

To find out where it's going run:

```
free -m
```

Comment: hi thomas... free -m gives similar numbers (http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/4156/screenshot1dx.png)  and the machine has a nVidia graphic card with dedicated memory. so, i'm kind of puzzled with the missing RAM.

Comment: the operating system and its data structures have to live somewhere: `cat /proc/meminfo` Don't worry, all your memory is there. Also there is the perennial confusion between GibiBytes and GigaBytes (for which I always have to puzzle out whether the SI or IEC prefixes are really meant). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte

gigabyte (GB)   10^9    2^30    gibibyte (GiB)  2^30

The manufacturer has supplied 8 * 10^9 Bytes of storage and marketed it as 8 GB.

8 GB * 1000 = 8000
8000 / 1024 (actual base two representation) = 7.8125  GB

Whats worse is if they actually did this the whole way:
8 * 1000  * 1000  * 1000 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 7.45 GB

Its the same way with Harddrive manufacturers.

And ISPs:  a 20 meg connection is 20 million bits not bytes.   In reality since 1 byte = 8 bits, its only a 2.5 MB connection rate at maximum.

Comment: This is the only correct answer.

Comment: Why you divide with 1024? A MB is defined as 10^3 KB.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw this with identical Ubuntu 18.04 installs on identical ThinkPad T430 laptops: one showed 8GB, the other 7.8GB.  Also it was slower, by quite a lot.

I compared setups until I found that one, because of the way Windows had been installed, had the wrong type of partition table: it was not GPT.

I used `gparted` to completely rewrite the partition table to a new GPT one, and reinstalled Ubuntu and Lo! 8GB memory and properly fast.

I don't know **why** this fixed it, but making the two machines identical **did** fix it.

Answer (score -3):

It's due to the 3GB limit, PCI, AGP and PCIe and the hard drives, USB controller and any other PCI device you can think of.

This actually eats 0.5GB+ of RAM space but it's remapped higher in RAM space, above 8GB because Ubuntu supports 64GB (maybe only 16GB, but it's remapped). I'm guessing 1.2GB of RAM is eaten by PCI devices and 1GB is remapped.

Comment: This is entirely incorrect from my knowledge..